# Problema ao setar valor de um campo BIT mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Uso `Java` + `Hibernate` em meus sistemas, criei um atributo `boolean` pra determinar se um usuário é administrador: `private boolean isAdmin;`

O `Hibernate` gera as tabelas e os campos, e esse campo isAdm passa a ser do tipo `BIT` no `MySQL`. Na versão que tenho instalada em minha máquina eu consigo entrar no `WorkBench` e setar os valores manualmente, ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na máquina local onde tenho a versão `5.6.23` do `MySQL` funciona, porém no servidor onde tenho instalada a versão `5.7.10` tenho o seguinte erro ao tentar atribuir o valor 1 no campo isAdm:

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to
>   the database. Executing: UPDATE `auditoriabd`.`usuario` SET
>   `isAdm`='1' WHERE `id`='2';
>
> ERROR 1406: 1406: Data too long for column 'isAdm' at row 1 SQL
>   Statement: UPDATE `auditoriabd`.`usuario` SET `isAdm`='1' WHERE
>   `id`='2'

Como posso resolver esse problema? Será que o problema ocorre pelo fato das versões do `MySQL` serem diferentes?

Comment: já tentou setar o column definition do atributo para BIT ? ex: @Column(columnDefinition = "BIT") ?

Comment: Ainda não, pra isso eu teria que mexer bastante na estrutura do sistema. Achei uma possível solução, vou testar.

Comment: Não precisa mexer em nada rs, é só colocar essa definição que eu falei em cima do atributo da sua classe :o)

Comment: Vou tentar, estava procurando uma solução no banco.

Comment: @wryel não deu certo